# R compare timestamps, which is earlier

Tags: r

In R, I found a very strange behavior.

```
> x
[1] "2018-10-20 00:20:44 UTC"
> y
[1] "2018-10-20 02:14:59 CST"
> x < y
[1] FALSE
```

How could we make them correct?

Comment: Can you run `class(x)` and `class(y)`?

Comment: Are they character strings or POSIX-time objects? Because `"2018-10-20 00:20:44 UTC"` and `as.POSIXct("2018-10-20 00:20:44 UTC")` print the same but are very different objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `CST` here?  Did you mean `America/Chicago`?

If I make that explicit, all is good:

```
R> library(anytime)
R> x <- utctime("2018-10-20 00:20:44 UTC", tz="UTC"); x
[1] "2018-10-20 00:20:44 UTC"
R> y <- anytime("2018-10-20 02:14:59 CST", tz="America/Chicago"); y
[1] "2018-10-20 02:14:59 CDT"
R> x < y
[1] TRUE
Warning message:
In check_tzones(e1, e2) : 'tzone' attributes are inconsistent
R>
```

And helpfully we a warning about comparison across timezones.

Comment: b/c `as.POSIXct("2018-10-20 00:20:44", tz = "UTC") ; as.POSIXct("2018-10-20 02:14:59", tz = "CST6CDT")` just aren't as classy, right? :-)

Comment: I happen to use `anytime` more as it is more flexible on inputs, and because I sometimes flip to its cousin `anytime::utctime()`.

Comment: I would expect no less. In truth, I use the `anytime` package _all the time_ for $DAYJOB, too. So much easier given the plethora of formats I have to work with across data sets.